# Intellij Idea Jupyter support not working

Tags: intellij-idea, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

At some point, support for Jupyter notebooks stopped working in IntelliJ IDEA. Notebooks are not being rendered, I can't find any Jupyter related configuration.

IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate - version 2023.3.2

Any ideas on what/where to check?

Answer (score 0):

It could be due to various issues, like corrupted installation, Jupyter plugin is accidentally disabled, etc.

For a quick solution, you can try deleting the [IDE directories](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/directories-used-by-the-ide-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs.html) and reinstall the IDE (of course, backup the settings first -- **File | Manage IDE settings | Export Settings...**).

If it doesn't help, or you don't mind doing some troubleshooting, consider submitting a [support ticket](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/?pycharm) with JetBrains, and attach logs from **Help | Collect Logs and Diagnostic Data**.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue with the same version you are.  Whacking/recreating venvs, reinstalling jupyter, etc. didn't help.

However, after contacting Jetbrains, they say they've now updated documentation that suggests you need to install the Jupyter plugin *in addition to* the Python plugin.

Link to documentation: https://www.jetbrains.com.cn/en-us/help/idea/ipython-notebook-support.html

Answer (score 0):

Same problem after upgrading to 2023.3.4, installing the jupyter plugin, and creating a new project in a python 3.12 virtual environment. Make sure you **also** have the jupyter package installed [per #2 from this Intellij help page](https://www.jetbrains.com.cn/en-us/help/idea/editing-jupyter-notebook-files.html). These steps in the IDE will do it: `File | Project Structure... | SDKs` then select the project's virtual environment. In the right pane click on the `Packages` tab, click the `+`, type "jupyter" in the search box, select the jupyter package, and click `Install Package`.